# Power supply BT-153 displays wrong voltage

Tags: power-supply, voltage, current

I have a BT-153 bench power supply (0-15V, 0-3A, see https://www.conrad.com/p/basetech-bt-153-bench-psu-adjustable-voltage-0-15-v-dc-0-3-a-45-w-no-of-outputs-1-x-393647) which displays an incorrect output voltage when under load. I wonder if it is broken, just poor quality or if I am misunderstanding what this power supply is supposed to do or show me.

When measuring the output voltage without a connected load, the displayed voltage matches my multimeter measurement to within a few tens of mV, so all is good. When setting, for example, the voltage to 12V and setting the current limit to max, a 12V / 20W light bulb draws around 1.5A, and the power supply and my multimeter agree to within 10-20 mA.

However, after connecting the bulb, the power supply still displays a voltage of 12V, whereas my multimeter measures around 10.6V. When connecting another, identical bulb in parallel, the current increases to 2.93A (multimeter confirms), the power supply continues to show 12V, but the multimeter measures 9.4V.

I am confused as to what the power supply is doing: it appears to show the value of the *desired* voltage, and even though it should be able to deliver 12V and 1.6A, it can't, but refuses to inform me about this. I expected that (a) the power supply's voltmeter acts like a multimeter, showing the actual voltage, and (b) that the voltage will not break down when the supply is put under a load of 50% of its nominal capacity.

Is this simply poor quality or misguided expectations on my behalf or am I misunderstanding what is going on?

Comment: Are you measuring the voltage under load at the power supply or at the load? (As the supply has shielded terminals, I suspect the latter.) Are you using leads of sufficiently low impedance? It looks to me as if you have a lead impedance of around an ohm, which would account for your readings.

Comment: As @henros suggests, you must make your voltage measurements directly at the power supply's output jacks if you want to check the supply itself. Is that what you are doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh no, how embarrassing. When I measure at the power supply's terminals all is good and as expected. It was indeed the resistance of the leads I hadn't accounted for. Thanks for your replies!

Comment: Hi, Thanks for confirming the solution. Please remember to accept an answer (i.e.. this one, if no better one is added) when you are able to do so (I know there might be a system-imposed delay, before you can accept your own answer). Thanks again.